# complex ActiveRecord to MongoID query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, mongodb, mongoid

could you please help me to convert active record query to mongoid?

```
where(["access_grants.access_token = ? 
AND (access_grants.access_token_expires_at IS NULL 
OR access_grants.access_token_expires_at > ?)",
conditions[token_authentication_key], Time.now]).joins(:access_grants).
select("users.*").first
```

Comment: Need to know more about what your Mongo Collection collections look like.  I'd be happy to help then.

Comment: thank, man! plz have look at provider's User model http://www.railsatwork.com/2010/10/implementing-oauth-provider-part-1.html - i work on migration this code to mongoid

Comment: So currently do you have your Mongo Collections defined? or are you working on those still?

Answer (score 0):

thank all, but i've got recipe how to solve this issue - http://groups.google.com/group/mongoid/browse_thread/thread/7d55c5687479355e

```
user_id = AccessGrant.where(:access_token => conditions[:token_authentication_key]).any_of({ :access_token_expires_at => nil }, { :access_token_expires_at.gt => Time.now).first.user_id 
user = User.find(user_id)
```